# Как сделать кнопку по умолчанию активной?

Tags: bootstrap

```css
#buttons .butn {
  padding: 3px 15px 3px 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  color: #bababa;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#buttons .butn:focus {
  background-color: #998675;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #998675;
  border-radius: 3px;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-1 col-xs-1"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-9 col-sm-11"> <button type="button" class="butn" value="focus">All</button> <button type="button" class="butn">Web Design</button> <button type="button" class="butn">Mobile App</button> <button type="button" class="butn">Illustration</button> <button type="button"
        class="butn">Photography</button> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: СSS
#buttons .butn {
    padding: 3px 15px 3px 15px;
    border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: white;
    color:#bababa;
    font-size: 14px;
}
#buttons .butn:focus {
    background-color: #998675;
    color:white;
    border: 1px solid #998675;
    border-radius: 3px;
    outline: none;
}

Comment: HTML   
<div id="buttons">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-1 col-xs-1"></div>
       <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-9 col-sm-11">
            <button type="button" class="butn" value="focus">All</button>
            <button type="button" class="butn">Web Design</button>
            <button type="button" class="butn">Mobile App</button>
            <button type="button" class="butn">Illustration</button>
            <button type="button" class="butn">Photography</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

Comment: не стоит писать код в комменты. Лучше попробовать разобраться

Comment: Кнопке можно назначить активный (нажатый) вид, а также заблокированное состояние. Класс `.active` отображает, как кнопка выглядит во время нажатия, а класс `.disabled` делает ее неактивной.

Comment: @Cricket и ответ стоит писать как ответ, а не как комментарий)

Comment: @Cricket спасибо, но я так пробовал и не получилось. можно расписать поподробнее пожалуйста.)

Comment: @антонтеличенко это потому, что в бутстрапе нет класса .butn, есть класс .btn. Потому класс .active и не работает

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать атрибут `autofocus` - [Подробнее](http://htmlbook.ru/html/button/autofocus).

> Атрибут `autofocus` устанавливает, что кнопка получает фокус после
>   загрузки страницы. Такую кнопку можно нажать сразу **без перевода на неё
>   фокуса**, например, с помощью клавиатуры.

```css
#buttons .butn {
  padding: 3px 15px 3px 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  color: #bababa;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#buttons .butn:focus {
  background-color: #998675;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #998675;
  border-radius: 3px;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-1 col-xs-1"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-9 col-sm-11">
      <button type="button" class="butn" value="focus">All</button>                   <button type="button" class="butn">Web Design</button>
      <button type="button" class="butn">Mobile App</button> 
      <button type="button" class="butn" autofocus>Illustration</button>
      <button type="button" class="butn">Photography</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```